# Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, passenger, phusion

I am trying to run rails with passenger and nginx. Nginx wont redirect to my rails app instead proceeding to its default index.html page, and I got this error:

> Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during startup: Cannot create a subdirectory inside instance registry directory /tmp: No such file or directory (errno=2) (-1: Unknown error)

Comment: Hey, did you got any solution for this? I'm facing same problem please help if you can.

Comment: Hey Jai, what I did is I created a new rails directory and i just let the app listen to other ports by adding here /etc/nginx/sites-available/default then restart the nginx

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
sudo sh -c 'echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope'
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope'
sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :22222
```

good luck!

Comment: please explain better your answer